# Javascript cookie set not working

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I have a fairly simple code that should hide my 'cookie-policy' bar on click, but it doesn't seem to store the cookie to remember the user clicked 'close'. My function:

```
function closeCookieBar() {
      document.getElementById('cookiespace').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('cookiepolicy').style.display = 'none';
          var date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
          var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
          document.cookie = cookiepolicy+"="+value+expires+"; path=/; domain=.mydomain.nl";

     }
```

The bars close just fine, so the first two lines of code are executed. However, if I
renew the page, the bar just shows up again. This is what I have a the cookie bar:

```
<div id="cookiepolicy" <?php if(isset($_cookie['cookiepolicy'])){ echo "style=\"display:none\""; } ?>>
<div id="cookiepolicy-wrapper">
<div id="cookiepolicy-txt">
<span id="cookiepolicy-notice">Deze website maakt gebruik van cookies om de functionaliteit en het gebruiksgemak te vergroten. Als u onze website gebruikt, gaan wij er vanuit dat u hiermee akkoord gaat. </span>
<span id="cookiepolicy-accept-cookies" onclick="closeCookieBar();">Sluit</span>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I put the '.' in front of my domain hoping that would fix my cross-suddomain problem, but the cookie isn't even stored for the main domain...

Hope anyone sees my error?
Thanks!

Comment: What is in the variable "cookiepolicy"?  Or is that supposed to be the string constant `"cookiepolicy"`?

Comment: You might want to consider using a plugin, could be making a manual or human error since cookie quite sensitive to the format;

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
<?php if(isset($_cookie['cookiepolicy'])){ echo "style=\"display:none\""; } ?>
```

To:

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['cookiepolicy'])){ echo "style=\"display:none\""; } ?>
```

as Pointy comment you might want to change your `document.cookie` and create a `value` variable like so:

```
value =  document.getElementById('your_item').value;
document.cookie = "cookiepolicy="+value+"; "+expires+"; path=/; domain=.mydomain.nl";
```

Answer (score 0):

This line does not seem quite right -

```
document.cookie = cookiepolicy+"="+value+expires+"; path=/; domain=.mydomain.nl";
```

1. it should be something like

   document.cookie = "cookiepolicy="+value+expires+"; path=/; domain=.mydomain.nl";
2. Is the value variable set?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, but both your suggestions didn't seem to fix my problem. For other people in the future with a similair problem, this code worked perfectly for me (even on my subdomains):

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/; domain=.example.com";
}

createCookie('cookieee','stuff','22');
```

Good luck!